# Wordpress Bootstrap Grid

Tags: wp-query, sidebar, twitter-bootstrap, register-sidebar

What's the best way to create a grid layout using bootstrap, or see link below http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/ displaying three different headings, should i use `wp-query` or, sidebars?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should use wp-query. Using a sidebar for this purpose will yield problems in the long term.

1. **SEO**: Sidebars are taken as "aside" content, which is considered less relevant content by search engines.
2. **Editor**: The editors for the sidebars are much worse than post editors.
3. **Reliability**: Any change to containers added in function will reset all content and setup.
4. **Scalability**: More functions available to work with on post.